# ¿Cómo repetir el juego hasta que el jugador lo decida?

Tags: c, bucle-for, random

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(){
int n, d1, d2,opciones, chicos, grandes, res, suma;
int vector[11]; // 2-12
int i;

printf("Digite el numero de jugadores que participaran en el juego:");
scanf("%i", &n);

for(i=1; i<=n; i++){

printf("\n Digite una de las opciones que desea 1.-Grandes o 2.-Chicos: "); scanf("%i", 
&opciones);
switch(opciones){
    case 1:printf("\n Introdujo Grandes\n"); break;
    case 2: printf("\n Introdujo Chicos \n"); break;
    default : printf("Introdujo un opcion no valida \n");
    return 0; 
}
system("pause");
srand(time(0));
    d1 = (rand() % (6 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    d2 = (rand() % (6 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    printf(" \n El valor de el primer dado es: %i \n", d1);
    printf(" \n El valor de el segundo dado es: %i \n", d2);
    
    res=d1+d2;
    printf("\n");
    
    printf("\n El resultado de las caras superiores de su tirada de dados es:%i\n ", 
res);
}

if(res<7){
    printf("\n Gana el jugador que eligio -Chico- \n");
}
else if(res>7){
    printf("\n Gana el jugador que eligio -Grandes- \n");
} 
else if(res==7){
    printf("\n La casa gana, todos los jugadores pierden");
}


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Tengo un problema en lenguaje C. Pero no se como repetirlo hasta que el jugador lo indique. Asimismo para los que estan más avanzados en este tema, si tienen alguna sugerencia que podría mejorar mi codigo se los agradecería mucho.

El juego de dados conocido como “Chicos y Grandes” es popular, realice un programa que simule dicho juego, a
continuación se muestran las reglas para los jugadores.

1. Un jugador tira dos dados. Cada dato tiene seis caras. Las caras contienen 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 y 6 puntos.
2. Antes de tirar los dados el jugador debe elegir entre Chicos o Grandes
3. Una vez que los dados se hayan detenido, se calcula la suma de los puntos en las dos caras superiores. El rango de la
   suma es de 2 a 12
4. Si a la primera tirada, la suma es inferior a 7, el jugador que eligió Chicos gana.
5. Si a la primera tirada la suma es superior a 7 el jugador que eligio Grandes gana.
6. Si a la primera tirada la suma es 7, entonces la casa gana
   Repetir el juego hasta que el jugador lo decida.

Comment: Puedes mover la lógica del juego a una función y luego será tan simple como usar un `while` como sugirieron en una respuesta o tu ciclo preferido llamando a dicha función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo debes declarar una variable char que sera 'y' o 'n' dependiendo si el usuario quiere repetir el juego o no. colocamos todo en un do while y al final preguntamos si se quiere continuar. El ciclo continuara mientras la variable sea 'y', sino sale de el.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(){
char willcontinue = 'y';
int n, d1, d2,opciones, chicos, grandes, res, suma;
int vector[11]; // 2-12
int i;

do{

printf("Digite el numero de jugadores que participaran en el juego:");
scanf("%i", &n);

for(i=1; i<=n; i++){

printf("\n Digite una de las opciones que desea 1.-Grandes o 2.-Chicos: "); scanf("%i", 
&opciones);
switch(opciones){
    case 1:printf("\n Introdujo Grandes\n"); break;
    case 2: printf("\n Introdujo Chicos \n"); break;
    default : printf("Introdujo un opcion no valida \n");
    return 0; 
}
system("pause");
srand(time(0));
    d1 = (rand() % (6 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    d2 = (rand() % (6 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    printf(" \n El valor de el primer dado es: %i \n", d1);
    printf(" \n El valor de el segundo dado es: %i \n", d2);
    
    res=d1+d2;
    printf("\n");
    
    printf("\n El resultado de las caras superiores de su tirada de dados es:%i\n ", 
res);
}

if(res<7){
    printf("\n Gana el jugador que eligio -Chico- \n");
}
else if(res>7){
    printf("\n Gana el jugador que eligio -Grandes- \n");
} 
else if(res==7){
    printf("\n La casa gana, todos los jugadores pierden");
}

printf("desea repetir el juego? (y/n)");
scanf(" %c",&willcontinue);

}while(willcontinue=='y');

}
```

Comment: Sugiero que le des formato al código para mejorar su legibilidad siempre y cuando no produzca problemas. En un lenguaje como Python donde el identado importa también se puede, pero hay que tener más cuidado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir un bucle while, justo cuando tiras, añades una variable que te sirva para contar si es la primera tirada, y la condicion de parada del while sería que el usuario digite un numero que indique que quiere salir. Puedes leer acerca de como funcionan los bucles while en la [documentación de Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/while-statement-c?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Creo que como tal no hay una documentación oficial. Sí están disponibles los estándares para comprar o conseguir gratis en algunos sitios.